# Ho to get a string till the last occurrence of a character

Tags: c++, string, stream, stringstream

***EDIT 1***

### I forgot to say that the string has to be taken from `cin`

I have a string like "Hi; my;; name is Andrea; and I like C++".
I want to create a stringstream initialized with that string and get everything before the last `;`.

This is what I've tried:

```
    string ex("Hi; my;; name is Andrea;; and I like C++"), text, final_text;
    stringstream loop_stream(ex);
    int findComma = loop_stream.str().find(';');
    do {
        getline(loop_stream, text, ';');
        loop_stream.ignore(1);
        final_text += text;
        loop_stream << loop_stream.rdbuf();
        findComma = loop_stream.str().find(';');
        while (findComma == 1) {
            loop_stream.ignore(1);
        }
        findComma = loop_stream.str().find(';');
    }
    while (findComma != string::npos);

    cout << "-" << final_text << "-" << endl;
```

but it doesn't work at all... I would like the output to be:

```
-Hi; my;; name is Andrea-
```

Comment: why to do that complicated stuff rather than to just search for last ';' using `string::rfind` then to get the expected substring using `string::substr` for instance ?

Comment: I think the OP didn't know you can do a search going backwards from the end of the string.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference where the string comes from if you create a function to solve the issue.  Maybe that is also why your code is much more complicated than it should be -- you were trying to write the code intermixing input routines with string manipulations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another solution using `find_last_of`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std:: string test = "Hi; my;; name is Andrea; and I like C++";
   auto pos = test.find_last_of(";");
   if ( pos != std::string::npos)
      std::cout << test.substr(0, pos);
}
```

Output:

```
Hi; my;; name is Andrea
```

---

Using a function:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string parseString(const std::string& s)
{
   auto pos = s.find_last_of(";");
   if ( pos != std::string::npos)
      return s.substr(0, pos);
   return s;
} 

int main()
{
   std::cin >> test;  // assume the string will be inputed
   std::cout << parseString(test);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I've just realized I've written a different question from what I had in my mind, I need to take the string from the `cin`

Comment: It shouldn't matter where the string comes from.  Take the code I posted, make it a function that returns a `std::string`, and call the function with the input string.

Comment: Is this suitable also if the user wants to start a new line?

Comment: There is a design principle in programming called [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).  It doesn't matter where or how the input string you are trying to parse comes from.  The function does one thing and one thing only -- gets a string that has all of those semicolons, and returns back to the caller the results.  It doesn't concern itself with where, when, or how the string it receives was produced.  As my comment in the main section noted, this is probably why your original solution was overly complex.

Answer (score 1):

How about something simpler, not using stringstream:

```
string ex("Hi; my;; name is Andrea;; and I like C++");
size_t pos = ex.rfind(';'); // find last semicolon
string final_text = ex.substr(0, pos);
```

Comment: Thank you but I've just realized I've written a different question from what I had in my mind, I need to take the string from the `cin`

Comment: @JohnBardeen: OK, then use `std::getline()` to take the entire string from `cin` then apply my solution.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't do it if the string can contain new line characters

Comment: You can either call getline() repeatedly  (my favorite approach), or call `cin.read()` with the maximum length of possible input into a single buffer (in which case you have to know the maximum length in advance).

Comment: All these things I'm asking are for a project given by my professor... The user should be able to edit the whole command while writing it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `istreambuf_iterator` to construct a `string` from everything that is in the `istream` (like `std::cin`). After that, just use one of the other answers to extract what you want:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<sstream>

int main(){
    std::istringstream loop_stream("Hi; my;; name is Andrea;; and I like C++");

    // read the stream until it's depleted and put it in a string:
    std::string all_stream(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(loop_stream),
                           std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{});

    // use any of the other answers, like this:

    std::string final_text;
    if(auto pos = all_stream.find_last_of(";"); pos != all_stream.npos) {
        final_text = all_stream.substr(0, pos);
    }

    std::cout << '-' << final_text << "-\n";
}
```

Output:

```
-Hi; my;; name is Andrea-
```

Answer (score -2):

you are stuck in repeating loop, check your condition of loop. I think there is some problem with findComma it's  value isn't updating.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.